# Rank Optimization over semi-definite constrains

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, nonnegative-matrices

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^m$, $L(X)$ and $L(Y)$ be the sets of linear operators of $X$ and $Y$, $\text{Herm}(X)$ and $\text{Herm}(Y)$ be the set of Hermitian operators of $X$ and $Y$. $Pos(X)$ represents the set of semi-definite elements of $\text{Herm}(X)$. $Φ: L(X)→L(Y)$ is called Hermitian preserving if $Φ(A)$ is always Hermitian for $A\in \text{Herm}(X)$.

We are interested in the following program defined by a tuple $(\Phi,B)$, where:

1.$\Phi: L(X)→L(Y)$ is a Hermiticity-preserving linear map,

2.$B \in \text{Herm}(Y)$.

The pair of optimization problems is as follows:

> maximize: rank $Z$
>
> subject to: $\Phi(Z) =B$,
>
> and $Z \in \text{Pos}(X)$.

Is there standard algorithm to solve this problem?

Moreover, we are interested in find some $M$ such that the rank of $M$ equals the value of the above optimization problem.

It is not SDP and it seems much harder than SDP.

Comment: Finite dimensional Hilbert spaces are $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ only.

Comment: @user64494, let it be $\mathbb{C}^n$.